# After updating framework from .Net6.0 to .Net7.0 I get following Error on my browser: HTTP Error 500.31 - Failed to load ASP.NET Core runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, .net-framework-version

In my Blazor server side app, I have updated the framework from .Net6.0 to 7.0 but got this error when I open the web page:

HTTP Error 500.31 - Failed to load ASP.NET Core runtime

I get this error on several client PC's when I try to open the page. When I check on these client PC's command line dotnet --info, I see that 7.0 is installed. What could be the problem?

.NET runtimes installed:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.16 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.16 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.16 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Comment: What is `client PC`?  PC with the navigator? SERVER in customer?

Comment: I mean the PC's from where the web application is opened. Not the server PC where the web application runs

Comment: .NET runtime is required only on the server that host the blazor server application.

Comment: More information in the documentation : [ASP.NET Core Blazor hosting models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models)

Answer (score 0):

After I have installed  ASP.NET Core 7.0 Runtime (v7.0.5) - Windows Hosting Bundle Installer on the server where my application is hosted, the problem was fixed.